# Program1 Accepts Input From User, Then Program2 Prints Out To Screen

Tags: c++

I have a server and a client program. Server program prompts user to enter text, then sends user input to client. The client prints out user text to screen. So far server program prompts user to enter text and when I run client program it displays nothing. Any recommendations to make programs work. Below are both programs.

```
// server.cpp
// g++ -o server server.cpp -lpthread -lrt
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

string UserInput(string);

#define SHMSZ 27
char SEM_NAME[]= "vik";


int main(void)
{
  char ch;
  int shmid;
  key_t key;
  char *shm,*s;
  sem_t *mutex;
  string input;

  //name the shared memory segment
  key = 1000;

  //create & initialize semaphore
  mutex = sem_open(SEM_NAME,O_CREAT,0644,1);
  if(mutex == SEM_FAILED)
    {
      perror("unable to create semaphore");
      sem_unlink(SEM_NAME);
      exit(-1);
    }

  //create the shared memory segment with this key
  shmid = shmget(key,SHMSZ,IPC_CREAT|0666);
  if(shmid<0)
    {
      perror("failure in shmget");
      exit(-1);
    }

  //attach this segment to virtual memory
  shm = (char*) shmat(shmid,NULL,0);

  //start writing into memory
  s = shm;

  // Enter user input
  //cout << "Enter your input: ";
  //cin >> input;

  // Display user input
  //cout << "You entered: "<< input << endl;

  //return 0;

  while(1)
    {
      cout << "Enter your input: ";
      cin >> input;
      sem_wait(mutex);
      //*s++ = count;
      sem_post(mutex);
      //return 0;
    }


  //the below loop could be replaced by binary semaphore
  while(*shm != '*')
    {
      sleep(1);
    }
  sem_close(mutex);
  sem_unlink(SEM_NAME);
  shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, 0);
  _exit(0);

}
```

-

```
// client.cpp
// g++ -o client client.cpp -lpthread -lrt
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace std;

string UserInput(string);

#define SHMSZ 27
char SEM_NAME[]= "vik";



int main(void)
{
  char ch;
  int shmid;
  key_t key;
  char *shm,*s;
  sem_t *mutex;
  string input;

  //name the shared memory segment
  key = 1000;

  //create & initialize existing semaphore
  mutex = sem_open(SEM_NAME,0,0644,0);
  if(mutex == SEM_FAILED)
    {
      perror("reader:unable to execute semaphore");
      sem_close(mutex);
      exit(-1);
    }

  //create the shared memory segment with this key
  shmid = shmget(key,SHMSZ,0666);
  if(shmid<0)
    {
      perror("reader:failure in shmget");
      exit(-1);
    }

  //attach this segment to virtual memory
  shm = (char*) shmat(shmid,NULL,0);

  //start reading
  s = shm;
  while(1)
    {

      cout << "You entered: " << input << endl;
      //cin >> input;
      sem_wait(mutex);
      putchar(*s);
      sem_post(mutex);
      return 0;
    }

  //once done signal exiting of reader:This can be replaced by another semaphore
  *shm = '*';
  sem_close(mutex);
  shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, 0);
  exit(0);
}
```

Comment: What does the debugger say?

Comment: I receive no error message. When I run server.cpp I enter my string input and program sits in a loop. Which is okay. I run client.cpp and the string input from server is not sending to client? Or maybe client.cpp isn't catching string input.

Comment: My program finally works. The issue was memory pointer was not referencing user input. Server code was not sending string input into memory location. Therefore client was not able to output to screen. How can I mark this page as solved?

Comment: If anyone is interested I'll show my code!

Comment: @ep7network: You can answer your own question in the answer box below this post, similar to the way you posted the question.